# Remove default border in -amp-accordion-header

Tags: html, css, amp-html

Not all bloggers like the default CSS value presented by AMP and I'm sure that AMPProject has handled all kinds of possibility for that.
Therefore, I need to remove the default border (`#DFDFDF`) in `.-amp-accordion-header` and change the background (`#EFEFEF`) into transparent and I get failed.

Here's its default html:

```
<div class="-amp-accordion-header" role="tab"
aria-controls="_AMP_content_0" aria-expanded="false">
```

As you know that we can't add `-amp-accordion-header` in our custom CSS element that makes it invalid AMP or not-validated!

in: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/1849/files, you'll see:

```
.-amp-accordion-header {
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #efefef;
padding-right: 20px;
border: solid 1px #dfdfdf;
}
```

Please help me whoever knows.pls.thnks.

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle link?

Comment: please provide more details

Comment: I'm asking about CHANGING the "DEFAULT" AMP's CSS property [border] value at class selector -amp-accordion-header. Please check again the file 'https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/pull/1849/files'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this is tricky but then this solves and works using `nested-accordion` class selector:

**CUSTOM-CSS:**

```
.nested-accordion{
background:transparent;
border:1px solid #fff;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<amp-accordion>
    <section>
      <h4 class='nested-accordion'>
          <span class='show-more'>MORE &#8595;</span>
          <span class='show-less'>LESS &#8593;</span>
      </h4>
      ..................
    </section>
</amp-accordion>
```